# Is to possible to find filename from http headers

Tags: c++, qt, network-programming, httpwebrequest, http-headers

Usually when downloading files, suppose using QNetworkAccessManager, the filename is not present at the end of link. How to get proper file names in that case. Even if link doesn't contain a hint of name, firefox always downloads the file with its proper name and extension. We can get a hint of extention using mime-types but what about file names.

Comment: Could you maybe add an example URL of something that "downloads" in Firefox but not in your program?

Comment: I did not say the program failed to download. The file is downloaded properly, there is only a file naming problem. I rename the file after download and it works fine. How to find the correct name of file from Url or header.You can try downloading an attachment from gmail.

Comment: It's hard to say for sure - we need a specific example - but you may be looking for the `Content-Disposition` HTTP response header.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. It's the `Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=<file name.ext>` header. There's a strong suggestion to set the content type to `application/octet-stream` so browsers and their plugins are not tempted to open it instead.