# How to download a file with it's name using curl (C++ or D)

Tags: c++, curl, d

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is to possible to find filename from http headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12505661/is-to-possible-to-find-filename-from-http-headers)

I am currently attempting to download a file using curl in D. This works fine using curl but it requires me to specify a file name rather than use the file name on the server. I've found many simalar posts to this but they all use php. Is there a way to do this using C or D?

Comment: can't you create a filename from the url? or generate a new one in the %temp% dir...

Comment: The filename isn't always in the url, I can create a new one but I like to have my files named appropreitely

Comment: You're assuming that there _is_ a filename on the server. I.e. that the "file" you're downloading is actually a file on the server. However, chances are that retrieving `http://example.com/random.php` gives you the output of a serverside script, not the script itself.